# Функция стандартной библиотеки для сравнения вещественных чисел С/С++

Tags: c++, c, математика, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Приходится часто делать сравнения с вещественными числами, и выполняю эту операцию следующим образом:

```
fabs(matrix_[i][j] - other.matrix_[i][j]) > EPS
```

Ранее я случайно находил метод который выполнял следующее:

```
bool fdif(a, b) {
  return fabs(a - b) > epsilon;
}
```

*Наведите на библиотеку и название функции которая выполняет данную операцию, буду очень признателен.*

Читабельность с тем методом была по приятней.

Comment: Вы неправильно сравниваете вещественные числа. Расстояния между соседними числами не постоянны, они разные в зависимости от числа. Другими словами, числа раскиданы по числовой оси неравномерно. Эпсилон это расстояние от единицы до соседнего числа. Расстояние от 1e+100 до соседнего числа намного больше, поэтому сравнивать разницу для чисел такого порядка с эпсилон бессмысленно. Эпсилон надо масштабировать, вот здесь есть пример того, как это делается: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon

Comment: В библиотеке Qt есть функция `qFuzzyCompare`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37105679/5767249

Comment: Вам для С++? В библиотеке [`boost::math`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/float_comparison.html) для сравнения чисел с плавающей точкой есть шаблоны `relative_difference` и `epsilon_difference`